# Query by a parent field but return a child class

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Is it possible to write a `Service` that provides a method that selects entities by a **parent field** but returns a **child class** that gets passed in by a parameter (or generic on the method)?

Assuming the `Parent` has a String field called flag and two childs `Child1` and `Child2`, the `ParentService` should be usable like this:

```
Child1 child1 = parentService.findFlag(Child1.class, "de");
Child2 child2 = parentService.findFlag(Child2.class, "de");
```

or

```
Child1 child1 = parentService.findFlag<Child1>("de");
Child2 child2 = parentService.findFlag<Child2>("de");
```

**Detailed example:**

Because it is quite hard to explain, this code should explain the scenario from above:

Java Classes:

- `Parameter` - abstract parent class having a common field for all childs

  - `UiParameter` extends Parameter
  - `BatchParameter` extends Parameter
- `ParameterService` - provides a `save(Parameter)` method that can be used for `UiParameter` and `BatchParameter` This method is used by other services to save all kinds of children

Now it would be handy to add a `find(UiParameter.class, commonFieldSelector)` or `find(BatchParameter.class, commonFieldSelector)` method to the `ParameterService`.

Currently there are 4 boilerblate classes (UiParameterService, UiParameterRepository, BatchParameterService, BatchParameterRepository) with just 1 method that looks almost similar.

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@DiscriminatorValue("PARAMETER")
public abstract class Parameter extends AbstractEntity
{
    // all children will share that
    @ManyToOne
    private Application commonField;
}

@Data
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class UiParameter extends Parameter
{
    private String foo;
}

@Data
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class BatchParameter extends Parameter
{
    private int size;
}

public interface ParameterRepository extends JpaRepository<Parameter, Long>
{
    // That works great, but it returns all kind of children...
    List<Parameter> findByCommonField(final Application commonField);
}

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class ParameterService
{
    private final ParameterRepository parameterRepository;

    public ... findByCommonField...(...)
    {
        return ... magic ...;
    }
}
```

The usual Service/Repository for all Childs approach leads in our case into boilerplate classes having just a `findFlag` method that gets copied from Child1 to ChildN.

Changing the Domain (inheritance strategy) will be a problem.

**Spring-Solution based on Maciejs answer:**

```
public interface ParameterRepository extends JpaRepository<Parameter, Long>
{
    @Query("SELECT e FROM Parameter e WHERE TYPE(e) = ?1 AND e.commonField = ?2")
    <E extends Parameter> List<E> findByTopic(final Class<E> e, final Application commonField);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's `TYPE` operator in JPQL, you can use it as following:

```
SELECT e
FROM EntityClass
WHERE TYPE(e) = EntityClassSubclass
```

You can use this query and then write generic method which casts results to desired type.

i.e.

```
private static <T extends SuperClass> List<T> queryForClass(Class<T> myClass) {

    Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM SuperClass p WHERE TYPE(p) = :myClass");
    q.setParameter("myClass", myClass);
    List<? extends SuperClass> resultList = q.getResultList();

    return (List<T>) resultList;
}
```

Comment: Based on your suggestion i added the spring solution to my question. Somehow adding it to our answer got rejected... Thank you.

Comment: Is it also possible to dynamically add criteria for `child` entities in a `parent` repository?